# How to make a dataframe of 0 and 1 such that each unique value is a column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following `df`

[image]

Then I would like to transform `df` into `df1` whose column are unique values of `df`. Take the first row of `df` as an example, its `year` is 2012 and its `report` is 4. then column `year_2012` and column `reports_4` take value 1. The other columns take value 0.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'year': [2012, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2014], 
        'reports': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Could you please elaborate how to obtain such result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [`pd.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html):

```
cols = ['year', 'reports']

pd.concat([pd.get_dummies(df[col], prefix=col) for col in cols],
          axis=1)
```

Or even easier, credit goes to [@ScottBoston](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6361531/scott-boston):

```
pd.get_dummies(df, columns=df.columns)
```

Output:

```
   year_2012  year_2013  year_2014  reports_2  reports_3  reports_4  reports_24  reports_31
0          1          0          0          0          0          1           0           0
1          1          0          0          0          0          0           1           0
2          0          1          0          0          0          0           0           1
3          0          0          1          1          0          0           0           0
4          0          0          1          0          1          0           0           0
```

Comment: I have many columns. Is there any way to do for all column, instead of repeating `pd.get_dummies(df['year'], prefix='year')`?

Comment: `pd.get_dummies(df, columns=df.columns)`

Comment: @ScottBoston duh, TIL this. Thank so much.

Comment: Thank you so much for your helpppp!